# angular.js url routing and html5Mode(true)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-routing, hashbang

I want to setup accessible and bookmarkable URLs that are routed by angular.js.

The application is only a part of the whole website accessible via http://example.com/application/

Whatever comes after `/application/` is a route param.

Now I want to have a URL that can be accessed either via

```
http://example.com/application/#/filter1/filter2/filter3/
                               ^ hashbang here
```

or

```
http://example.com/application/filter1/filter2/filter3/
                              ^ no hashbang here
```

and I would expect angular.js to pass my route params to my application, but instead I get routed through .otherwise.

**Basic Route Setup**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // this requires base-tag to be set in dom, 
                                   // but doesnt work for me

$routeProvider
    .when('/application/:filter1/:filter2/:filter3', {
        action: 'filter',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/application/' + filter1 + '/' + filter2 + '/' + filter3
    });
```

In the **HTML** of that application I put `<base href="/application/" />`, which seems to work fine, but reloading the page or re-visiting it after it went through the .otherwise-route doesn't work and the server says "Page not found".

When I disable HTML5 mode and remove the base-tag, it doesnt work either and I get routed through .otherwise

Comment: It is your server's responsibility to response with the same page on both /application/ and /application/filter1/filter2/filter3/ requests, while you didn't provide any details on your server side.

Comment: ok, but how about routing with hashbang? doesnt work either - instead it takes the .otherwise-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your server knows `application/` (and return maybe `application.html`) but not `application/filter1/filter2/filter3/` (because `filter3.html` does not exists).

You can:

- Decide to use only the hash syntax (the server read everything before the `#` and let the browser (in your case, angular) to manage everything after.
- Set up your server so that every path that starts with `application/*` return to the browser `application.html`.

Moreover I think you need to remove the base from the route provider:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/:filter1/:filter2/:filter3', {
    action: 'filter',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/' + filter1 + '/' + filter2 + '/' + filter3
});
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I dont want to touch the server setup. Instead angular should take everything after # and use it as params but this isnt the case, instead I get charAt(d) is undefined. When I debug a little I get to $$.parse withoutbaseUrl or so which seems to care about the hashbang and fails in my case

Comment: Thanks squaleLis, I have setup URL Rewriting for the Hash and now it works just fine!